# How do I make a POST AJAX call without using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an ajax call without jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

I have a function where I need to make an update to my database using an ajax call. For speed reasons, I would prefer it if I didn't have to include the jquery source file on this page and therefore use the $.ajax function to perform my post request to the php file, although this would make performing the ajax call via POST a lot easier.

I have seen on here how to do this using the GET method but have not found any help for doing a non-jquery ajax call using the POST method. Since this call will make changes to my database, I do not want to use the GET method.

UPDATE:

Going the jquery route:
The actual task performed is lower priority to loading the rest of the page. Is there any way I can guarantee that the ajax call (including loading jquery) is the very last javascript thing to go off as the page loads?

Comment: Have you googled it? Should be really easy to find an example.

Comment: I did not think that the jQuery source file would slow down a site that much. Maybe an alternative is to use the Google one so that it may be cached from going to another site that referenced it?

Comment: If you Google for "ajax javascript -jquery", you'll find 100s of tutorials. Keep in mind that doing such thing is not as easy as using a library (JQuery or other) because it's browser-dependent (i.e. you have to write different code for different browsers ... mainly IE vs. everything else).

Comment: jQuery 1.8.2 gzipped and minified is roughly 30KB... I'd say it's worth the AJAX abstraction (especially considering cross-browser issues).

Comment: Yeah, I already use the google cdn, gzipped, and minified version of jquery, I was just curious if I could make gains in speed before trying the easy route.

Comment: The actual task performed is lower priority to loading the rest of the page. Is there any way I can guarantee that the ajax call (including loading jquery) is the very last javascript thing to go off as the page loads?